# Numpy gradient function for bidimensional arrays returns first the gradient component in y direction, and then in x direction

Tags: python, matlab, gradient

This is quite counter-intuitive and opposite to what happens in MATLAB.
Testing code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = np.arange(-20, 21, 1)
y = np.arange(-20, 21, 1)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

Z = 6 -2 * X + Y + 2 * X ** 2 +3 * X * Y + Y ** 2

grad_X = np.gradient(Z)[0]
grad_Y = np.gradient(Z)[1]

# Point where to calculate the gradient
x0 = -2
y0 = 2

grad_X_x0 = grad_X[(X == x0) & (Y == y0)][0]
grad_Y_y0 = grad_Y[(X == x0) & (Y == y0)][0]
```

Comment: Its because of how np arrays are ordered. In any case, is there a question here?

Comment: The point is that I expect the first component of the gradient to be in the x direction. The matrix Z is exactly the same as in MATLAB, why are the gradient components in the reversed order?

Comment: Because that is how python works. Data is stored differently in python, the first index is the "outermost". Do not expect python to work like matlab, because it is not supposed to, its a different programming language.

Comment: Thank you. It is still counter-intuitive to me, but it is like it is.